# mysql broke software center, nautilus, and dpkg - nothing installs

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, mysql

Tried to install mysql-server 5.5 and 5.6, then mariadb-server. There is a bug report for mysql-server. Recommended is mariadb. That won't install either. Tried to install synaptic - dpkg errors from all three. Lost nautilus somewhere along the way. Using terminal and Krusader.

Need help repairing this mess, and installing a database - one or the other. Most of the errors are subsystem dpkg - Error (1) that prevent installation.

Comment: What was the original error when you tried to install mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible fix run
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get install --fix-missing

sudo apt-get purge mysql*

whereis mysql (This is needed because in most cases config files are left behind,  so as to make reinstalling easier)

Remove all files,  if any,  listed from above.

sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mysql-server  (The order is required to help eliminate dependency problems.

Answer (score 0):

The literature pointed to a debian flag file to delete if wanting to downgrade mysql from v6 to v5. Removing the flag file was the right answer for my system. Repair was allowed to proceed, and the system is giving hugs to v5.